# My spring boot with Gradle giving me a null modelAndView object

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

So this is my first web project with spring boot and Gradle, and I have done the same steps as mentioned in the get started with spring boot. 
Even though the building process is ok and the dependencies seems to be also ok, however whenever I call the controller /firstapp I get a null view, even if I tried to return a string I have a Whitelabel Error Page. 
This is my project.

Project directory picture:

[image]

Test controller :

[image]

main class :

[image]

Application.properties :

[image]

build.gradle :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What’s the actual error that you are getting? The model is null because you have created a ModelAndView with only a view name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *.html in the spring.mvc.view.suffix property instead of .html

Comment: did not work. the problem is not only reading the file but also when I just return a string rather than a viewandmodel object it still giving me a whitable error.

Comment: Did you have a view resolver ?   `@Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to my bad directory configuration, the spring-boot could not read the Viewresolver from the application.properties and also the controller class should be in a subdirectory under the main springapplication.

[image]